# Creating Android .jar files

Tags: java, android, jar

I want to create an Android project that contains some code, and then export that code as a .jar file to use it on another Android project.
I've already tried to create an Android project and set it as a library in the properties, and then export the project as a jar file.
 Aparently everything works fine, when I use my .jar file as a user library in another Android project my code inside the .jar is visible and everything compiles fine. But when I run my application it closes and say that it could not find the classes inside the .jar file.
Any sugestions will be very appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your JAR is in the `libs/` directory of the project using the JAR, and that it is in your build path in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Look at Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Order and Export. Make sure your jars are exported as well as imported.

Comment: I have moved the referenced jar file to top and my problem get resolved.